# Bad address error when reading into mmapped DMA buffer

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, dma

In my Linux device driver I have the following mmap implementation:

```
static int device_mmap(struct file *f, struct vm_area_struct *vma) {
    struct device_user *u = f->private_data;
    dma_mmap_coherent(&u->device->pdev->dev,
        vma, u->data, u->data_dma, u->data_size);
    return 0;
}
```

I basically try to map allocated DMA coherent buffers from kernel memory into user space.

Then, in user-space application I do the following:

```
#define DATA_SIZE 0x4000
#define INPUT_DATA_SIZE 0x1000

fd = open("/dev/mydevice", O_RDWR);
input_fd = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY);
char *data;
data = mmap(NULL, DATA_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
char temp[DATA_SIZE];

// a) Returns bad address in errno
read(input_fd, data, INPUT_DATA_SIZE);

// b) Works ok, when used later with device
read(input_fd, temp, INPUT_DATA_SIZE);
for(int i = 0; i < INPUT_DATA_SIZE; i++)
    data[i] = temp[i];
```

I'm wondering why a) doesn't work even though it seems b) works correctly when using device later with data passed in `data` buffer. Possibly I'm using `dma_mmap_coherent()` the wrong way, but I can't find any docs, that would help me fix my problem.

In code above, `u->data_size` is bigger than `DATA_SIZE`, so size of returned mmapped memory shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: `data` stores memory address returned from `mmap`.  `data` is used again in `read()`.  Why?

Comment: I want to read data from `input_fd` into `data` buffer, so that device could see it.

Comment: Here is man on `read`: `read() attempts to read up to count bytes from file descriptor fd into the buffer starting at buf`.  I am guessing.  `read` command wants a NUL terminated char array as the second argument.  `data` may or may not be NUL terminated char array.

Comment: `data` is not a buffer.  `data` is a pointer. In order to make it into a `buffer`, it needs to have a fixed size.

Comment: After each `read()`, make sure the read was successful.

Comment: @Nguaial *I am guessing. read command wants a NUL terminated char array as the second argument.*  No.  Not at all.  *`data` is not a buffer. data is a pointer. In order to make it into a buffer, it needs to have a fixed size.*  `data` is a pointer to memory - also known as a **buffer**.

Comment: @qiubit What does `read()` return?  You're ignoring the return value - don't do that.  Also, what happens if you `memcpy()` from `temp` to `data`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle - What if `data` does not have NUL character?  Does that still qualified to be a `buffer`?

Comment: @Nguaial `read()` tries to read the requested amount of bytes from the given file descriptor and places what's read starting at the address provided. The actual value(s) of the bytes don't matter - they're simply placed into the memory starting from the address provided. Then the actual number of bytes read is returned.  `NUL` characters are irrelevant and are treated as any other byte value.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, read returns -1 in case of a) (as I said it saves bad address error in errno), and INPUT_DATA_SIZE in case of b) (as I said b) works correctly).

Comment: Intuition tells me that I need to modify vma in my device driver in order for everything to work, but I have no idea where to look for further clues

Comment: @qiubit - Could it be that mmap() is returning memory address where it is read only?  So it has a failure of storing to `data`.  Check the memory address that is returned from mmap().

Comment: @qiubit If `errno` is `EFAULT`, I'd start looking through the kernel source to see where you're getting that from, and see what conditions cause `EFAULT` to be returned.  Maybe you simply need to pass different flags to your `open()` and/or `mmap()` calls?

Comment: `read()` can return anything from 0 to asked size.